# Taxonomy Category Permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am working on a custom post type that is using a custom taxonomy called "portfolio-category".

Now I am trying to list the categories under this taxonomy - with the relevant permalink.

Listing them is fine - cannot seem to find the right terms to display the permalink though (currently noted as a # on the code below).

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    // your taxonomy name
    $tax = 'portfolio-category';

    // get the terms of taxonomy
    $terms = get_terms( $tax, [
        'hide_empty' => true, // do not hide empty terms
    ]);

    // loop through all terms
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {

        // if no entries attached to the term
        if( 0 == $term->count )
        echo '<li><a href="#">' .$term->name. '</a></li>';

        // if term has more than 0 entries
        elseif( $term->count > 0 )
        echo '<li><a href="#">' .$term->name. '</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer (annoyingly just after posting - sorry).

For anyone else wanting to know, the markup is:

```
<?php
    // your taxonomy name
    $tax = 'portfolio-category';

    // get the terms of taxonomy
    $terms = get_terms( $tax, [
         'hide_empty' => true, // do not hide empty terms
    ]);

    // loop through all terms
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {

        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

        // if no entries attached to the term
        if( 0 == $term->count )
        echo '<li><a href="' .esc_url( $term_link ). '">' .$term->name. '</a></li>';

        // if term has more than 0 entries
        elseif( $term->count > 0 )
        echo '<li><a href="' .esc_url( $term_link ). '">' .$term->name. '</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please "accept" the answer if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   $args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category', // your taxonomy name
    'hide_empty' => true,
    );

// get the terms of taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( $args ); // Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument in the $args

// loop through all terms
if( is_array( $terms ) && count( $terms ) > 0 ){
    $html = '';
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {

        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
        $html .= '<li><a href="' .esc_url( $term_link ). '">' .esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo $html;
} ?>
```